# How to test init function with @Postconstruct and map inside with junit mockito

Tags: java, testing, junit, hashmap, mockito

I have a class to test but i dont know how to test it. Can somebody help for test?

```
@Component
public class KvkkCorrBankingExecuter {

    private final Map<String, IKvkkCorrBankingExecuter> operationMap = new HashMap<>();

    IKvkkCorrBankingExecuter executer;

    @Autowired
    DemandBoeExecuter demandBoeExecuter;

    @Autowired
    DemandCleanBaExecuter demandCleanBaExecuter;

    @Autowired
    DemandGuaranteeExecuter demandGuaranteeExecuter;

    @Autowired
    DemandLcExecuter demandLcExecuter;

    @Autowired
    DemandSlcExecuter demandSlcExecuter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        operationMap.put("DEMAND_BOE", demandBoeExecuter);
        operationMap.put("DEMAND_CLEAN_BA", demandCleanBaExecuter);
        operationMap.put("DEMAND_GUARANTEE", demandGuaranteeExecuter);
        operationMap.put("DEMAND_LC", demandLcExecuter);
        operationMap.put("DEMAND_SLC", demandSlcExecuter);
    }
}
```

Map line and the init function are red highlighted in the covarage. They need to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

I wont give a readymade answer, but some guidance. I would advice you to try it out,  that is the only way to learn and remember.

**How to write unit test for this class ?**
The goal of the unit test would be to test all possible scenarios. The goal should not be just to make the code coverage report red, but to avoid any possible bugs in that code for various data conditions.

Since you are testing through jUnit, do following:

1. Create a test class - give class name such that it indicates what class is being tested. e.g. KvkkCorrBankingExecuterTest.java
2. Write a method with name that says what condition you are testing.
   e.g.  testInitFunction()
3. Since you are not using spring for test, the @Postconstruct annotated method won't be called automatically.

Because the test does not use spring, the autowired attributes will be null.
For that, create Mock variables with exact same definition as the class being tested.

Then do following:

```
Class KvkkCorrBankingExecuterTest{
//other mock variables similar to demandLcExecuter

@Mock 
DemandLcExecuter demandLcExecuter;
  
@Before
public void init(){
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testInitMethod(){
 //  1. Create an instance of KvkkCorrBankingExecuter 
 // 2. Call init() method on that instance
 // 3. Validate that the size of operationMap is 5
 // 4. Validate that you get values corresponding to each key. The value will be // equal to the mock attributes in this class.
   
}

}
```

**Other code suggestions:**
Make attributes private.

Comment: The problem is when i called init function i cant get the operationMap.